# HTML Select inside a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

Basically I'm trying to give user a 5min countdown to choose one option and if he doesn't when time's over, it automatically assumes one of them. Trying to do it with Java Script, where it creates a deadline variable (5min ahead of current time) and when it's over (T=0) will pick option 1, but if user answers before deadline, it should break the while loop. I do not know if I'm explaining myself well.

Here's my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">

    var timeInMinutes = 5;
    var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
    var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes*60*1000);

    function getTimeRemaining(deadline{
      var t = Date.parse(deadline) - Date.parse(new Date());
      return {
        'total': t
      };
    }

while (t> 0){
    </script>
        Option <select name="opt">
            <option value="1">Basic</option>
            <option value="2">Complete</option>
            if($_MIG['opt'] != null){
                break;
            }
        </select>

        <?php

        ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm not sure where to finish the < script >, this is not working how i want it to, any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) for this kind of functionality.

You can do:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  let el = document.querySelector("select[name='opt']");
  if (el.value == 0) {
    el.value = 1;
  }
}, 300000 /* 5 min*/ );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  Option
  <select name="opt">
    <option value="0">Select an item</option>
    <option value="1">Básica</option>
    <option value="2">Completa</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, keep in mind that there are other problems with your markup and PHP. With some practice, it will get easier to catch.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks, this really is my first time working with PHP/HTML/JavaScript. That looks like it could do the job, just have one more question, how can i break from the timeout? If user answers before the 5min timeout, so he doesnt have to wait

Comment: The block of code I provided will not run if the user selects an option :). Just let it run through. glhf

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much, as I said I'm pretty noob at this